# Convert MemberExpression to string

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression, expression-trees

In the following method I'm trying to make an Expression using the `List<string>().Contains()` method.

The problem is that the value I need to check if exists in the list is not of type string and therefore I need to convert it.

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, bool>> GenerateListContainsExpression(string propertyName, List<string> values)
    {          
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
        var method = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains");
        var comparison = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(values), method, Expression.Constant(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(string))));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(comparison, parameter);
    }
```

This gives me an error saying:

> "No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' and 'System.String'."

It is not guarantied that the value is of the type `int?`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain how `List<string> values` fits in what you are trying to do?

Comment: It's a system to categorize books based on a value of the book. In that regard it should be possible to enter a comma-separated value, which will be translated to a list, which is then checked to see if the property on the Books object exists in the list.

Comment: What are the possible types of the `propertyName` property? Does it make sense for it to be something other than a string?

Comment: No, a string will always make sense :-)

Comment: Yes, but does it make sense to be an int? How can you search for an int in a `List<string>`? Would the list in this case contain integers as strings like "1","12"?

Comment: In that case, the list would contain integers as string yes. But yes, you could say that it would make sense for the list to be integers in that case. I'm fine comparing them as strings though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke `ToString` on the property value first. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, bool>> GenerateListContainsExpression(
    string propertyName,
    List<string> values)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);

    var contains_method = typeof(List<string>).GetMethod("Contains");

    var to_string_method = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");

    var contains_call = Expression.Call(
        Expression.Constant(values),
        contains_method,
        Expression.Call(property, to_string_method));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, bool>>(contains_call, parameter);
}
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Thank you!